# Почему обратная ссылка в отношениях @ManyToOne null?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Что я делаю не так?
Есть Entity `Order`, которая имеет `OrderItem` со связью `@ManyToMany`

```java
public class Order {
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "order",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems;
}

public class OrderItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Dish dish;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Order order;
}
```

Вот я пытаюсь сохранить `Order` и заодно вывести перед сохранением содержимое.

```java
public Order saveOrder(Order order) {
    System.out.println("SERVICE saving order " + order);
    return orderRepository.save(order);
}
```

Я вижу, что `Order` в себе имеет `OrderItem`, который имеет обратную ссылку `null` (я так понимаю, эту ссылку должна заполнить Spring data jpa).

> SERVICE saving order Order(id=0, orderItems=[OrderItem(id=0,
> quantity=2, order=null)])

Но когда я сохраняю в БД, обратная ссылка `null` так и остается. А из-за того, что стоит `mappedBy` и `owner` отношений `OrderItem` - связи нет никакой между Entities, я не могу фетчнуть `OrderItem` через `Order`.

Вот как я вижу это в БД.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так, где ошибся с мапингом?

Был бы очень благодарен за помощь, Т.к. я только учусь и самостоятельно понять, где ошибка мне очень сложно.

Comment: Для этого надо смотреть SQL.

Comment: @RomanC я вижу в sql, что hibernate персистит объект с обратной ссылкой null.
Вопрос в другом, почему hibernate этот null сам не проставляет?

Comment: чтобы он проставлял надо делать апдейт, но hibernate не знает откуда брать ссылку.

Comment: @RomanC

Как мне указать это hibernate?
Неужели остается только делать вот так


https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1381626/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-hibernate-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8

Comment: Это дубликат вопроса. Одну проблему надо решать в одном вопросе.