# Ставит ли Hibernate обратную ссылку при автоматически?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

У меня есть  Order, который имеет

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy ="order")
List<OrderItem> orderItems;
```

А OrderItem имеет обратную ссылку

```
@ManyToOne
Order order;

При сохранении Order я сам вручную должен проставить для каждого OrderItem обратную ссылку?
Как-то так?

OrderItem orderItem1 = new OrderItem( //constructor );
OrderItem orderItem2 = new OrderItem( //constructor );
List orderItems = Arrays.asList(orderItem1, orderItem2);
Order order = new Order( orderItems);

orderItems.forEach(orderItem -> orderItem.setOrder(order); // вот так?
```

Hibernate и spring data jpa ведь самостоятельно обратную ссылку не ставят?

Если ставят, то прошу обратить внимание на этот вопрос [Почему null в обратной ссылке?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1381449/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-manytoone-null)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему обратная ссылка в отношениях @ManyToOne null?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1381449/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85-manytoone-null)